# UVM: connecting sequencer+monitor with a scoreboard

Tags: monitor, agent, uvm

I would like to connect a scoreboard with sequencer+monitor of an agent. Connecting the monitor is straightforward by using an analysis imp (*uvm_analysis_imp*) since the monitor holds an analysis port.

However, I am not sure how to connect sequencer and scoreboard since the sequencer holds a *uvm_seq_item_pull_imp* and it is not possible to simply connect it to an analysis imp. My idea was to check the port that is used by *uvm_driver* instead, that is *uvm_seq_item_pull_port*.

Unfortunately, it does not seem to be common to connect sequencer and scoreboard, but for my purposes it would be necessary. Is it only possible to use the *uvm_seq_item_pull_port* for the sequencer-scoreboard connection or is there an easier way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Doing this kind of connection between an active component (sequencer or driver) is generally frowned upon, due to reusability aspects (I'm contractually obliged to say that :D). It might make sense at SoC level though.

What you could do is create your own sequencer class (you probably have one already) that contains an analysis port. You'd have to extend `send_request(...)` to also write the item on that analysis port. You could then connect this analysis port to the scoreboard as you would for a usual monitor:

```
class some_sequencer extends uvm_sequencer #(some_item);
  uvm_analysis_port #(some_item) aport;

  function void send_request(uvm_sequence_base sequence_ptr, uvm_sequence_item t, bit rerandomize = 0);
    some_item item;
    if (!$cast(item, t))
      `uvm_fatal("CASTERR", "Can't cast")
    super.send_request(sequence_ptr, t, rerandomize);
    aport.write(item);
  endfunction
endclass
```

You can find a working example on [EDAPlayground](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/RM8) (note: I took some shortcuts from the accepted UVM coding guidelines).

Comment: Hi Tudor! This solution worked for me, thanks! I already had the impression that it is "frowned upon" to do such kind of connections. However, could you please elaborate why it is problematic concerning reusability aspects?

Just a small remark for your code example: *aport* should be named *some_port* here

Comment: I came across that similar implement but  "uvm_sequence_item item !$cast(item, t)" I want to know the reason of casting. Is there any special reason?

Answer (score 0):

This solution is possible but can limit the re-usability at SoC level. if you want to re-use your UVM environment at SoC level, then better connect SB with monitors. the reason is that on the soc level, your stimulus might be coming from other block e.g., CORE, and, in that case the transactions(stimulus applied to your block) should be caught by the monitor.